# how to extract info out of my JWT tokens identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt

I'm implmenting my own oauth authtentication system and want to use JWT tokens.
The ms implementation is a little confusing. I see the following hashing algorithum all over the net

```
public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];

        string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"];

        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);

        var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);

        var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;

        var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

        return jwt;
    }
```

but can't seem to find out how I can then extract the user info out of the token

Answer (score 0):

what you are showing is a JWT protect implementation that does not come out of the box. This is for serializing & encrypting tokens not the oposite. If you have already managed that part (that's the difficult one) then reading the user claims out of a JWT token should be easy. This is usually done by the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` middleware

```
 var issuer = "http://myidentityserverurl.com"
 var audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
 var symmetricKey = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

 // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AuthenticationType = "JWT",
                AllowedAudiences = new string[] { audience } ,
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[] 
                { 
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, symmetricKey)
                }
            });
```

Check out this [github repo](https://github.com/tjoudeh/JWTAspNetWebApi)  and the accompanying article [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/) for a complete example end to end.

Comment: for what purpose  `as:AudienceId` and `as:AudienceSecret` used for?

Comment: @Rahul AudienceId is equivalent to a relying party name or in other words the consumer of the JWT token. In the protect code above we are creating a token for a specific audienceId using a signing key. Those 2 must be known when you try to consume the tokens.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give an example code for consuming the JWT token from a  .c# client. Also if you can provide an example code to consume it from RestSharp client. Should I pass the 'AudienceId' and the 'AudienceSecret' to the server from client during the authentication process? How can I access the Claims in the client?

Comment: @Rahul I think what you need is ask a new question in SO. (I would use the [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel) lib to help me do that)

Comment: FYI. I have added a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968854/how-to-consume-jwt-access-token-and-user-claims-using-restsharp