# How to consume JWT access token and user claims using RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, restsharp, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm using below code to consume JWT access token from an Asp.net Web Api 2.2 service. I have followed [this article](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/) to setup an authorization server in Web Api service. I'm using RestSharp in the client.

client code:

```
            var client = new RestClient(http://localhost:58030);
            client.Timeout = 30000;
            var request = new RestRequest(@"/Oauth/Token", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddHeader("username", "admin@example.com");
            request.AddHeader("password", "Admin@456");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            result = response.Content;
```

As a result I'm getting following error:

```
{
  "error_description":"grant type not supported",
  "error":"unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

1. Why I'm getting this error and how can I fix this?
2. How can I access the Claims such as username in client?
3. Alternatively how can I use Identity Model to consume the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added `grant_type` ,`username` and `password` to the `Header` of the http request , it should be in `Body` part.

Answer (score -1):

It's an old question and you probably have an implementation by now but fwiw here is the solution that worked for me

```
var client = new RestClient("http://blahblah/");
var request = new RestRequest("/token", Method.POST);
// all parameters need to go in body as string
var encodedBody = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&grant_type=password", model.Username, model.Password);
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", encodedBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```